# how to solve × Build failed. Standalone build failed! in android expo?

Tags: apk, react-native, expo

I am a beginner to expo. I would like to generate APK,
using expo build: android but I get this error (× Build failed.
Standalone build failed).
Please, how to solve this problem.?
thank you

Comment: You need to provide way more details, the full error, your build settings, I don't know what else, but anything relevant to help you

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you change your icon in the **app.json** icon extension **.png** required then delete *.expo* file in your project then
**expo build:android -c**